# Prevent predicate pushdown post scan in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to disable an optimization performed by spark.

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (11)
+- Project (10)
   +- Project (9)
      +- BroadcastHashJoin Inner BuildRight (8)
         :- Project (3)
         :  +- Filter (2)
         :     +- Scan orc  (1)
         +- BroadcastExchange (7)
            +- Project (6)
               +- Filter (5)
                  +- Scan orc  (4)


(1) Scan orc 
Output [2]: [id#70, segment#71]
Batched: false
Location: InMemoryFileIndex [file:/....]
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)]
ReadSchema: struct<id:string,segment:array<struct<ids:bigint>>>

(2) Filter
Input [2]: [id#70, segment#71]
Condition : ((size(array_intersect(segment#71.ids, [100,200,300,400]), true) > 0) AND isnotnull(id#70))
```

If you see in the plan above, Spark is adding a post scan filter which does an `array_intersect`. The `array_intersect` actually happens on 9th step in Project again.

```
23/08/03 09:06:50 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Pushed Filters: IsNotNull(id)
23/08/03 09:06:50 INFO FileSourceStrategy: Post-Scan Filters: (size(array_intersect(segment#71.ids, [100,200,300,400]), true) > 0),isnotnull(id#70)
```

This post scan filter does not really help me and it increases my job execution time by 50%. If I do a `.cache()` and prevent this push down my job runs much faster.
However as this dataset is huge adding a `.cache()` uses a lot of disk (upto 100TB)

How can I disable this post scan filter in Spark without using cache? I tried using excludeRules but it doesn't seem to work

`.config("spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules", "PushDownPredicate")`

code:

```
spark.read.orc(s"input")
  .select(
    col("id"),
    col("segment.ids").as("segment_ids"),
  )
 .join(otherSmallDf, Seq("id"), "inner")
 .select(
    someUDF(col("id")).as("userId"),
    col("segment_ids")
  )
 .withColumn("segment_ids", array_intersect(col("segment_ids"), shareableSegmentIds))
 .where(size(col("segment_ids")) > 0)
 .write.option("sep", "\t").csv("output/path")
```

Comment: please share code

Answer (score 0):

The only predicate which is pushed down is:

```
PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id)]
```

the other filter can only be applied *after* the scan.  If that code and plan is representative then you probably want to move the where("segment_ids is not null") up *before* the join.  As it stands Spark can only evaluate the array_intersection then test the result.  The only way for segment_ids have a null is if the original segment.ids is null (so test it higher up anyway) or if shareableSegmentIds is null.

```scala
spark.read.orc(s"input")
  .select(
    col("id"),
    col("segment.ids").as("segment_ids"),
  )
 .where("segment_ids IS NOT NULL") // check if the underlying field is null
 .join(otherSmallDf, Seq("id"), "inner")
 .select(
    someUDF(col("id")).as("userId"),
    col("segment_ids")
  )
 .withColumn("segment_ids", array_intersect(col("segment_ids"), shareableSegmentIds)) // assuming shareableSegmentIds is not null (if it is use an empty array lit)
 .write.option("sep", "\t").csv("output/path")
```

This won't help you filter out shareableSegmentids any faster though, you can't push down array_intersect, pushdown [source filters](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/filters.scala) can only be simple binary comparisons and In, which isn't applicable here as you want intersection.

Comment: I need the where to be after the array_intersect because I need to filter out rows that are empty after the intersection. So if I add
`df.where(size(col("segment_ids")) > 0)` ... the problem still exists..

Comment: I updated the code in my question to have size check instead of null. I guess that lead to the confusion that I am filtering out nulls but I am actually filtering out rows after the intersect and Spark thinks it is too smart and tries to do it in a post scan filter

Comment: This doesn't change moving the filter up, you are logically forcing a filter after a join, do it before the join.  If this still doesn't make sense to you, or you have tried it and found no performance difference then post a more complete code sample so others can try to help.  Spark isn't "thinking" at all, it's doing what you told it to do.

Comment: I dont understand what relation this has with the join? Even if I remove the join it will still execute the array_intersect twice once in Filter and then in Project...I dont understand why does it have to do it twice.

Comment: I removed everything and did `read -> array_intersect -> size > 0 -> write`

It still did it this way..
`read -> size(array_intersect) > 0 -> array_intersect -> write`

Comment: I want it to just follow what I told it do and not add another array_intersect by itself thinking that will be faster because it executes slower in my case